# Is there a way to turn on and off the Mouse Keys feature using AppleScript or a terminal command?

Tags: macos, terminal, applescript, mouse, accessibility

I'm running Mac OS X 10.7.2. Is there a way to run an AppleScript or terminal command that quickly turns on or off the "mouse keys" feature under the Universal Access tab? Ideally I'm looking for a solution that doesn't involve GUI scripting the System Preferences app, although that would be slightly better than nothing.

I've explored `defaults write com.apple.universalaccess useMouseKeysShortcutKeys 1` and various other forms of that statement, but to no avail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the GUI scripting solution:

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    reveal anchor "Mouse" of pane id "com.apple.preference.universalaccess"
    tell application "System Events"
        tell process "System Preferences"
            tell first window
                tell first tab group
                    tell radio group 1
                        if value of radio button 1 is 1 then
                            # enabled, so disable
                            click radio button 2
                        else
                            # disabled, so enable
                            click radio button 1
                        end if
                    end tell
                end tell
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
    quit
end tell
```

It will launch *System Preferences* if required, but doesn't show the window and quits it afterwards, so from a UI POV, it at least doesn't show the window.

---

You can change the persistent setting on which the System Preferences configuration is based using the following commands:

```
defaults write ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.universalaccess mouseDriver -bool YES
defaults write ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.universalaccess mouseDriver -bool NO
```

Unfortunately, this only changes the configuration file and does not apply the changes to the running system.

---

While you can programmatically press *Option* keys using AppleScript, like the following:

```
tell application "System Events"
    key down option
    key up option
end tell
```

The *press Option five times to toggle* setting is at a higher level and doesn't get triggered by this. While all regular `Option` key presses are ignored after you only run `key down option`, you can still toggle Mouse Keys.

---

Debugging *System Preferences* while changing the setting shows calls to `LaunchUAServerIfNeeded` and `UAMouseKeysSetEnabled` in the private `UniversalAccessCore` framework. Unless we reverse engineer that framework and write our own binaries, I don't think we'll get a proper programmatic way to do this.

Comment: A phenomenal answer that only got better with the edit. Well done!

Comment: how do you find out what the anchors are called? I guessed 'Keyboard' and 'Hearing' but I can't seem to guess what the anchor name for the Seeing tab should be. It's not Seeing, Sight, Vision.... What I'm really curious about is how to find them, without guessing.

Answer (score -1):

Can't you use keystroke scripting in AppleScript for this?

Something along the lines of:

```
tell application "System Events"
    repeat 5 times
    //any of these should work
    key option
    key code 58
    key code option
    //I do not know if this works
    keystroke option
end tell
```

Comment: No, sadly, as far as I can tell, option is a modifier, not a scriptable keystroke.

Comment: @Daniel The commands would be `key down option` and `key up option`, but don't work, even with `delay 0.1` between each.

Comment: @Daniel Did you try it?

Comment: I did. Didn't trigger the switch when run. Be careful to never mismatch a pair of these when you try. AFAIK it's impossible to release a key pressed this way unless with the correct `key up`.

Comment: Yes I tried and no, it doesn't work. :-(